# How can i display the JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

I created a `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`, but its not showing in the program.

Here is my code:

```
        scrollPaneTable = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPaneTable.setBounds(10, 507, 854, -480);
        
        table = new JTable();
        table.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        table.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED, Color.GRAY, null));
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {"PC", "Computer", "Dominik", "Test", "Test"},
            },
            new String[] {
                "Name", "Beschreibung", "Nutzer", "Ort", "Seriennummer"
            }
        ));
        table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        table.setVisible(true);
        scrollPaneTable.setViewportView(table);
        jFW.getContentPane().add(scrollPaneTable);
```

Comment: Of course your JTable doesn't show up.  There's no main method, no JFrame defined.  Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Here is the Full Code:
https://hastebin.com/aqafafuray.java

Comment: 1) *"Here is the Full Code:"* Don't post links to code at external sites. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a main method, you initialize UI and create JTable etc. in the Constructor of Gui class.

You need to create new Gui object in main to see Frame Table etc. (Not neccesarily inside the Gui class)

Comment: I created a main and the window is showing. But not the Table. Every single Button, Label, etc. is working